# Vaadin: Opening a new window with PDF content placed in a String variable

Tags: string, pdf, window, vaadin

I'd like to open a new window with PDF content that is placed within a String variable.
I already have a button with an event connected. In this event I want to call the new window.

The method looks like this:

```
private void show_archivobjekt(String data) {
String pdf = anfrage.get_archivobjectdata(data);
System.out.println(pdf);  // This shows my PDF content in console and works!

    // How to convert this String into a StreamSource

    StreamResource streamResource = new StreamResource(pdfss, "test.pdf",  myView);
    streamResource.setCacheTime(5000);
    streamResource.setMIMEType("application/pdf");
    myView.getMainWindow().open(streamResource, "_blank");
}
```

**myView** is the Application.
How can I convert the **String pdf** to a StreamSource (**pdfss**)? Do I have to save it as file at first or is it possible to convert it to a StreamSource directly in memory?

The console output shows me the typically PDF content starting with %PDF-1.3 ... and so on.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Rainer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is available through the official support forum here: https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/148544

Simply create your StreamResource like this, by using the byte representation of your string to create a ByteArrayInputStream as the source:

```
StreamResource streamResource = new StreamResource(
    new StreamResource.StreamSource() {
        public InputStream getStream() {
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(pdf.getBytes());
        }
    }, "test.pdf");
```

Comment: I had some problems with the right generations of the PDF without encoding the getBytes(). So I added **pdf.getBytes("ISO-8859-1")** to get the best solution for me. I have embedded images in the PDF, that were causing those problems. Now everything works fine.